# Removing black background when publishing Image Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, image-service

I have a mosaic dataset that I want to publish as Image Service via ArcGIS Server.

I know how to set a background RGB value and display it as transparent in ArcMap.

Is there a way to do that when I publish the Image Service?